# Sending a "like" request to Facebook without the og tags in <head>

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to post stories like "John likes a photo at example.com", I was able to trigger it by using the og tags in the url  area:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="398192236928167" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Sample Title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/photo_large_thumbs/6396.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/6396" />
<meta property="og:type" content="myappname:photo" />
```

This only works from PHP code if I post it as an "object" and the only value I provide is the URL containing the above tags.

`$response = $facebook->api("/me/og.likes", "POST", array('object')=>'http://www.example.com/6396');`

Can I send the title, image, etc in the request (array) ? If so, how should the keys be formatted?

Comment: The whole _concept_ of Open Graph is that OG objects are identified by their URL, and deliver the relevant meta data _from_ that URL. If _“John likes a photo a example.com”_, that photo should have a unique address already – that other users can visit to see what it actually was that John liked. So it makes no sense to me trying to “circumvent” using a URL here.

Comment: For liking a photo, yes it would work well simply by the og <head> tags, but I was thinking there must be a way to pass the values, for things like "John likes a COMMENT on example.com", when I cannot have multiple OG tags on same page. I found some workarounds/hacks for this, usually done by redirects to an unique "object url" for each comment.

Comment: Any OG object can only be of _one_ type. If you want John to be able to like a photo and a comment separately, then those two obviously have to be two separate Open Graph objects.